# Is this usage of a HashMap thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, scala, thread-safety

I happen to work in a project which uses [mapperdao library](https://github.com/kostaskougios/mapperdao).
Occasionally, it throws an exception which suggests that the library is not thread safe. I could not figure out why though.
The issue happens in [this code](https://github.com/kostaskougios/mapperdao/blob/a33f4f8e1504e946046c1203b5f5a2c6881ded4b/src/main/scala/com/googlecode/mapperdao/lazyload/LazyLoadManager.scala):

```
    type CacheKey = (Class[_], LazyLoad)

    private val classCache = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[CacheKey, (Class[_], Map[String, ColumnInfoRelationshipBase[_, Any, Any, Any]])]

    def proxyFor[ID, T](constructed: T with Persisted, entity: EntityBase[ID, T], lazyLoad: LazyLoad, vm: ValuesMap): T with Persisted = {
        (...)
        val key = (clz, lazyLoad)
        // get cached proxy class or generate it
        val (proxyClz, methodToCI) = classCache.synchronized {
            classCache.get(key).getOrElse {
                val methods = lazyRelationships.map(ci =>
                    ci.getterMethod.getOrElse(
                        throw new IllegalStateException("please define getter method on entity %s . %s".format(entity.getClass.getName, ci.column))
                    ).getterMethod
                ).toSet
                if (methods.isEmpty)
                    throw new IllegalStateException("can't lazy load class that doesn't declare any getters for relationships. Entity: %s".format(clz))
                val proxyClz = createProxyClz(constructedClz, clz, methods)

                val methodToCI = lazyRelationships.map {
                    ci =>
                        (ci.getterMethod.get.getterMethod.getName, ci.asInstanceOf[ColumnInfoRelationshipBase[T, Any, Any, Any]])
                }.toMap
                val r = (proxyClz, methodToCI)
                classCache.put(key, r)
                r
            }
        }

        val instantiator = objenesis.getInstantiatorOf(proxyClz)
        val instance = instantiator.newInstance.asInstanceOf[DeclaredIds[ID] with T with MethodImplementation[T with Persisted]]

        (...)
}
```

`instantiator.newInstance` throws `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` for a class, which is supposed to be dynamically compiled and its name put into the map.

This code seems to be thread safe to me as any operation on the map is performed in the synchronized block. I can not figure out a scenario, when a map returns a class name, which is not generated and compiled yet. Am I missing something?

One other explanation is that the class is compiled, but it's not visible to the current class loader. I don't know how this can happen though and why this happens occasionally though.

UPDATE:
The track trace looks like:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mypackage.MyClass_$2
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor57.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:56)
        at com.googlecode.mapperdao.lazyload.LazyLoadManager.proxyFor(LazyLoadManager.scala:63)
        at com.googlecode.mapperdao.jdbc.impl.MapperDaoImpl.lazyLoadEntity(MapperDaoImpl.scala:338)
        at com.googlecode.mapperdao.jdbc.impl.MapperDaoImpl.$anonfun$toEntities$5(MapperDaoImpl.scala:301)
        at com.googlecode.mapperdao.internal.EntityMap.$anonfun$get$1(EntityMap.scala:46)
```

UPDATE 2: I finally found the root cause of my issue. It is a concurrency problem indeed, but not in the code I pasted. It's in [MImpl class](https://github.com/kostaskougios/mapperdao). 
What is happening here is dynamically generated class being compiled correctly, but it's initialization fails occasionally due to concurrency issue in [MImpl class](https://github.com/kostaskougios/mapperdao). Next time the code tries to instantiate the class ends up with NoClassDefFoundException thrown by JVM.

Comment: The problems seems to be related to a missing class in classpath, not related to thread safety... can you post the error stacktrace?

Comment: @Lorelorelore, the missing class is dynamically created and compiled in createProxyClz method. I'll add an example strack track to the description.